# NullReference exception on reactivation of app before a call to a MobileFirst adapter returns

Tags: windows-phone-8, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am developing a windows phone 8 silverlight application and I am using 
MFP v6.3

The following problem occurs.

If I make a call to a MobileFirst adapter and place the app in the background before that call returns, when I reactivate the app it crashes with this exception.

```
ExceptionObject {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at IBM.Worklight.WLRequest.responseCallback(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__1b(Object state2)}  System.Exception {System.NullReferenceException}
```

This happens for any call I have tried.
Does anybody know why this exception is thrown?

Secondly, I would like to know if there is a way to cancel a call. So that I can do it when my app is deactivated.

**EDIT: adding adapter call implementation**

```
public void getInvoices(IShowAndProceed showAndProceedVM, JObject parameter)
        {
    String myContextObject = "MyAppWP8";
    WLRequestOptions invoicesOptions = new WLRequestOptions();
    invoicesOptions.setInvocationContext(myContextObject);
    WLProcedureInvocationData InvoicesInvocationData = new WLProcedureInvocationData("BillingAdapter", "MyInvoicesProcedure");
    InvoicesInvocationData.setParameters(new Object[] { parameter });

    WLClient.getInstance().invokeProcedure(InvoicesInvocationData, new InvoicesInvokeListener(showAndProceedVM), invoicesOptions);
}
```

Comment: Mention your Worklight/MFP version instead of the .dll version.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Will, it's not a duplicate.

Comment: I edited the question to mention the MFP version

Answer (score 1):

Question #1:
An exception sounds like a defect to me. It will be investigated, but it will help if you will edit the question and add your implementation (for the adapter procedure call).

Edit: Please open a PMR.

Question #2:
It is not possible to 'cancel' a MFP adapter request after it has been executed. [You can submit a feature request](https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help/).

Comment: Please open a PMR for the crash.